# How to print specific characters in a line using python?

Tags: python-3.x, regex

I am trying to write a script to print specific words after a particular string.

Here is the input file

```
Theyare "playing in the ground", with friends
Theyare "going to Paris", with family
Theyare "motivating to learn new things", by themselves
```

In the output I am trying to select "are" as the keyword and after "are" I want the text which is in the "" and I want to add the text before space to the "".

output should be

```
They playing in the ground
They going to Paris
They motivating to learn new things
```

I can print the rest of the line with the below code but not certain words. So far I have

```
with open ('input.txt', 'r') as f:
    for lines in f:
        a = re.search(r'\bare', f):
            if a:
                print (lines)
```

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Use a regular expression to extract the parts of the line you want.

```
with open ('input.txt', 'r') as f:
    for lines in f:
        m = re.match(r'(.*?) are "(.*?)"')
        if m:
            print m.group(1) + " " + m.group(2)
```

The groups in `m` return the parts of the line that matches the patterns between `()`.

Answer (score 0):

If your lines always look like the examples you provided you can use string manipulations:

```py
    s = 'They are "playing in the ground", with friends'
    are_split = s.split('are')
    # are_split = ['They ', ' "playing in the ground", with friends']
    quote_split = are_split[1].split('"')
    # quote_split = [' ', 'playing in the ground', ', with friends']
    print(are_split[0] + quote_split[1])
    # 'They playing in the ground'
```